# Molecules and atoms

Tags: molecules

Which contains the fewest molecules?
Which contains greatest number of atoms?

- 0.5 g of hydrogen
- 4.0 g of oxygen
- 11.0 g of carbon dioxide

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**4.0g of Oxygen** has the fewest amount of atoms since H2 has more atoms than O2 (2 atoms) and Carbon (12/18 (if we include the electrons) atoms) also has more atoms than O2 (2 atoms).

**0.5g of Hydrogen** has the most amount of atoms - since Hydrogen is the least dense from them all.
Hydrogen density - 0.08988 g/L
Oxygen density - 1.429 g/L
Carbon density - 2.25 grams per cubic centimeter

I tried to explain with the best of my ability.

Comment: For homework questions we have a [policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) where you do not simply post the answer without explanation but rather that you give hints that lead the asker towards their own solution. We are not a homework completion service.

Comment: Oh, thanks for warning me. I'll keep that in mind for future answers of mine. Sorry.

Comment: This is not a homework just doing some revision and wanted to check that Im doing right. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: No problem, I also added the explanations as Bon said.